# Python Sympy. Непонятное I

Tags: python, sympy

Непонятный ответ решения системы уравнений

```
from sympy import *
a = input()
i = 0
arr = a.split(';')
for element in arr: 
if element.find("<=")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find(">=")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find("=<")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find("=>")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find(">")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find("<")!= -1:
    arr[i]=sympify(element)
elif element.find("=")!= -1:
    arr[i] = sympify("Eq(" + element.replace("=", ",") + ")")

i=i+1

print(solve(arr))
```

Ввожу 4*x-3*y=5;(256*x^4)+81*(y^4)=97

Ответ должен быть 1/2;-1 и 3/4;-2/3

Выводится, но еще какая то лишняя фигня: `[{x: 1/2, y: -1}, {x: 3/4, y: -2/3}, {x: 5/8 - sqrt(151)*I/8, y: -5/6 - sqrt(151)*I/6}, {x: 5/8 + sqrt(151)*I/8, y: -5/6 + sqrt(151)*I/6}]`
С некоторыми уравнениями нет такого.
Что это?
И еще вопросик, как сделать не систему уравнений, а совокупность? Желательно, чтоб было в строке.

Comment: Sympy дополнительно вывел комплексные решения системы, а вы рассматриваете только вещественные. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634728

Comment: Я попробовал добавить символ с real, но выводится [], пробовал отсортировать как было показано в квадратных скобках, но ошибка: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_real'. 
Не ругайтесь только, просто мне сложно на языке динамической типизации)
Но если это не система уравнений, то прекрасно работает.